# If $\mathbf{A} \succeq 0 \in M_n (\mathbb{C})$, why $a_{ii} a_{jj} \geq |a_{ij}|^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite

If $\mathbf{A} = [a_{ij}] \succeq 0 \in M_n (\mathbb{C})$ is positive semi-definite, why $a_{ii} a_{jj} \geq  |a_{ij}|^2$ $ \forall i,j \in \left\{ 1,\cdots,n\right\}$?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume it's actually $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ so I don't have to check about sesquilinearity conventions. The argument is the same, I just always forget which argument is linear and which one is conjugate linear in the complex case.

Notice that $a_{ij}=e_i^T A e_j$, where $e_i$ are the columns of the identity matrix. Then the statement is essentially a case of Cauchy-Schwarz for the "inner product" $\langle x,y \rangle = x^T A y$. I say "essentially" because this is not really an inner product because it is only positive semidefinite instead of positive definite. Nevertheless the proof of (the nonstrict form of) Cauchy-Schwarz goes through the same with this weaker assumption.

Comment: I deliberately considered $\mathbb{C}$ field since most of the proofs consider $\mathbb{R}$, then I was wondering whether the same argument holds for $\mathbb{C}$ field as well.

Comment: @user550103 The same argument works, just a conjugate may float around in the complex case depending on how exactly you write the proof.

Comment: Understand, thank you. 

On the other hand, just out of curiosity, if $a_{ii}a_{jj} = |a_{ij}|^2$, then why $A$ is non-invertible?

Comment: Look at $(e_i + c e_j)^T A (e_i +c e_j)$ for an appropriate $c$.

Comment: $\left(e_i + ce_j\right)^T A \left(e_i + ce_j\right) = c^2a_{jj} + 2ca_{ij} + a_{ii} $. Then, how does it explain that this is singular?

Comment: i can start another thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2767913/if-a-in-m-n-and-a-ii-a-jj-a-ij2-a-is-singular

Comment: The point is that if $a_{ii} a_{jj}=|a_{ij}|^2$ then dropping the modulus still gives an equation if you multiply by some $e^{it}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is Cauchy - Schwartz inequality for the inner product $(x,y) \to \langle Ax,y \rangle$ If you denote $\langle Ax,y \rangle$ by $\langle x,y \rangle '$ then the inequality simply states that  $\langle e_i,e_j \rangle ' \leq \langle e_i,e_i \rangle '\langle e_j,e_j \rangle '$.

Comment: I think one of the assumption should be that $A$ is symmetric as well, which is true for all positive (semi) definite matrices. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. For complex matricies positive definiteness implies symmetry.