# If $A = [a_{ij}] \succeq 0 \in M_n$, and $a_{ii} a_{jj} = |a_{ij}|^2$, why $A$ is singular?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A \in M_n$, $A \succeq 0$ is positive semidefinite, and $a_{ii} a_{jj} = |a_{ij}|^2$, then why $A$ is a non-invertible matrix?

Thank you in advance

p.s.: this problem is in "Matrix Analysis" by Horn and Johnson, second edition (please see [7.1.P1] page 434).

Comment: Are these two separate questions? If they are related, please explain how. If not, consider asking two different questions. See also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6464

Comment: No not really, my thinking (which can be wrong) is that the condition $a_{ii} a_{jj} = |a_{ij}|^2 \Rightarrow x^T A x = 0$. Or?

Comment: Ok! What is $x$?

Comment: I have updated above. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think the matrix with first row $(4,2)$ and second row $(-2,1)$ is invertible.

Comment: Are you working over $\mathbb R$? or $\mathbb Z$ by any chance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not true.
$$
\det\pmatrix{1&1&-1\\ 1&1&1\\ -1&1&1}=-4.
$$

**Edit.** Under the new assumption that $A$ is positive semidefinite, the problem statement is true. Note that the $2\times2$ principal submatrix $A(\{i,j\},\,\{i,j\})$ is singular. Therefore, there exists some nonzero vector $v\in\mathbb C^2$ such that $v^\ast A(\{i,j\},\,\{i,j\})v=0$. In turn, by embedding $v$ in a longer zero vector, there exists a nonzero vector $x$ such that $x^\ast Ax=0$. Hence $A$ is singular.

Comment: @user550103 It **is** invertible. That's why I said your hypothesis isn't true.

Comment: I have removed my hypothesis. However, the main question is still valid. Please see the comment from @daw, that $\det A = 0$ is true for symmetric $A$ and $n =2$ at least

Comment: @user550103 Throwing in the symmetry condition would make the statement true for $n=2$ only. It's still false for $n=1$ or any $n\ge3$.

Comment: You can also move the relevant entries to the upper left corner and say that the first principal minor is zero hence we are done.

Comment: Thank you very much. And apologies for the missing assumption. Now, I have accepted your argument. I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 2):

The claim is true for $n=2$ and symmetric $A$, as then $\det A=0$ follows from the conditions on $a_{ij}$.

Comment: i am sorry, I should have added that $A$ is positive semi-definite.

Answer (score 1):

This is false for a general (possibly non-symmetric) positive semidefinite matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
is positive semidefinite (its associated quadratic form is $x^2+y^2$) yet invertible

Comment: So, I guess 'Matrix Analysis' by Horn and Johnson do assume that all the considered positive (semi)definite matrices are symmetric/Hermitian. May be someone can comment that.